# MySQL statement wanted to query related custom post type posts in WordPress data base

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

Using a WordPress plugin called [Pods](https://pods.io), I have two custom post types defined: *venue* and *event*. Besides plain meta fields, Pods allows for defining so called 'relationship' fields between post types.

In my case, I use such a 'relationship' field in *events*, relating an event to a *venue*. Pods stores the post_id of the related *venue* post as a meta_value for the *event* post.

Now, in WordPress' admin I want to extend the edit view for my custom post type *events*. I want to make the list of *events* sortable by *venue*.
My question is, how must a MySQL statementlook like to achieve this? I have troubles to wrap my head around the fact that both, *events* and *venues*, are stored as posts in the wp_post table.

The relevant schema is as follows:

```
wp_posts
(id
,post_title
,post_type
)

wp_postmeta
(meta_id
,post_id
,meta_key
,meta_value
)
```

I am looking for something like

```
SELECT t1.post_title AS event_title
     , t2.meta_value AS venue
  FROM wp_posts AS t1 
  JOIN wp_postmeta AS t2 
    ON t2.post_id = t1.id 
 WHERE t1.post_type = 'event' 
   AND t2.meta_key = 'event_venue'
```

The statement above gets me the title of events along with the id of the related venue. With this id I'd need to query wp_posts and wp_postmeta again (`... WHERE t1.post_type = 'venue' ...`) to retrieve the title and other fields of the related venues. So, how to do this in one query?

Bunjip.

**Please note:** this question is *not* about how to extend the WordPress admin or how to use WP hooks to show custom columns in post lists nor how to make these lists sortable by custom column. All I need is the proper SQL statement. That's why I did not post my question to wordpress.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Strawberry: Look, both events and venues are posts in WordPress terms. They are posts of custom post types. Events have a custom meta field labeled 'event_venue' which contains the post_id of any post of custom post type 'venue'. I have edited the pseudo SQL statement to clearify.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following, which both answers the question AND explains how to ask it...

Note that when using an EAV such as this, it's still useful if possible to structure your data so that you can utilise data types. So, dates, strings and integers all go into separate tables.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS wp_posts;

CREATE TABLE wp_posts
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,post_title VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
,post_type VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO wp_posts VALUES
(1,'Adele at the O2','event'),
(2,'Springsteen at Wembley','event'),
(3,'Twickenham Car Boot Sale','market');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS wp_postmeta;

CREATE TABLE wp_postmeta
(post_id INT NOT NULL
,meta_key VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
,meta_value VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(post_id,meta_key)
);

INSERT INTO wp_postmeta VALUES
(1,'venue','The O2 Arena'),
(1,'date','2016-03-08'),
(2,'venue','Wembley Stadium'),
(2,'support_act','Dan Patlansky'),
(2,'date','2016-03-09'),
(3,'venue','Twickenham Car Park'),
(3,'date','2016-03-08');



SELECT p.*
     , venue.meta_value venue
     , support_act.meta_value support_act
     , date.meta_value date
  FROM wp_posts p
  LEFT
  JOIN wp_postmeta venue
    ON venue.post_id = p.id
   AND venue.meta_key = 'venue'
  LEFT
  JOIN wp_postmeta support_act
    ON support_act.post_id = p.id
   AND support_act.meta_key = 'support_act'
  LEFT
  JOIN wp_postmeta date
    ON date.post_id = p.id
   AND date.meta_key = 'date'
 WHERE p.post_type = 'event';

+----+------------------------+-----------+-----------------+---------------+------------+
| id | post_title             | post_type | venue           | support_act   | date       |
+----+------------------------+-----------+-----------------+---------------+------------+
|  1 | Adele at the O2        | event     | The O2 Arena    | NULL          | 2016-03-08 |
|  2 | Springsteen at Wembley | event     | Wembley Stadium | Dan Patlansky | 2016-03-09 |
+----+------------------------+-----------+-----------------+---------------+------------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @Strawberry. As far as I understand, you are suggesting a slightly different data model than I was using. While I understand your approach, I am afraid that it does not solve my problem. I can't change the data structure the way you suggested if I want to stay concise with the rest of my WP application. So, venue data sets must also be stored in the wp_posts table. In fact, they are referenced as single objects in other parts of the application too.

Comment: @Bunjip This example EXACTLY follows your data model.

Comment: Oops, so I must have gotten something wrong here... I just cannot recognize where venue posts are inserted into the wp_posts table. Hence, I assumed the data model would be different ...

Comment: Allright, got it. Your data model actually is different from the one I described in my question. The difference is that the meta_value of meta_key 'venue' is *not* a string but a post_id which again refers to a wp_post post of post_type 'venue'.

Comment: No. While your real model may be different, my answer corresponds to the model provided in the question: "`meta_key = 'event_venue'`". Either way, it is trivial to adjust/extend the query accordingly.

Comment: Maybe I should add that the SQL statement in my original question is not a valid query yet. I was just using it to demonstrate the direction I want to go to. So again, in my model `meta_value` for any `meta_key = 'event_venue'` is just a `post_id` of a related 'venue' post type post which has it's own meta fields, e.g. `meta_key = 'venue_name'` that I am actually after to retrieve and to sort by and stuff

Comment: Well, if nothing else, you now know how to ask a better question.